# not printing the pyramid properly

Tags: javascript

Hi I am tying to print pyramid using javascript in vscode but it is not getting printed properly. It is directly going to the else part. It is giving output as only spaces and one *.

```
const prompt= require("prompt-sync")();
let n= parseInt(prompt(" enter the number of rows: "));
var x,y;
for(x=1; x <=n; x++)
{
   for (y=1; y<(2*n)-1; y++){
    if(y<= n-(x-1) && y>=n+(x-1))
    {
      console.log("*");        
        }
        else{
            console.log(" ");
        }
  } 
}
```

```
expectation:
  *
 ***
*****
Output: *





//only spaces got printed and 1 *
```

Comment: use a debugger, we are not your debugging service

Comment: for each `x` print `n-(x-1)` and `n+(x-1)` and see where you go wrong

Comment: actually new to coding so didn't knew how to use debugger but thanks now I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your solution.

Firstly, the reason one `*` was being printed, is in your if statement: `if(y<= n-(x-1) && y>=n+(x-1))`.
This is impossible for anything greater than 1, as it is testing if y is less than or equal to your number and if it is greater than or equal to your number. The Signs need to be swapped around to give you:
`if (y >= n - (x - 1) && y <= n + (x - 1)) {`

Secondly, you use `console.log()`. This will add a new line after every message, which is what you don't want, so you can use `process.stdout.write` instead, and then output a new line (`\n`) in the first for loop after every row.

Thirdly in your second for loop, your condition is: `for (y=1; y<(2*n)-1; y++){`. This will print one to little characters on the last row, therefore simply change the ineqaulity to a `<=` to give you:
`for (y = 1; y <= 2 * n - 1; y++) {`

This gives a solution of:

```js
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
let n = parseInt(prompt(" enter the number of rows: "));
var x, y;
for (x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= 2 * n - 1; y++) {
        if (y >= n - (x - 1) && y <= n + (x - 1)) {
            process.stdout.write("*");
        } else {
            process.stdout.write(" ");
        }
    }
    process.stdout.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the explaination, it works